Qt6 How to clear internal terminal of QtCreator from C++?
Qt6 How to clear internal terminal of QtCreator from C++ without using Qt?
system("cls"); and system("clear"); does not work.Terminal outputs: "TERM environment variable not set." for system("clear");and"sh: line 1: cls: command not found" for cls.

Does this answer your question? How clear screen in QT console? (basically the first result of a google search)

No. I need a solution without using Qt classes. C++ and API of operating system only. And for internal terminal of QtCreator. For external terminals system("cls"); and system("clear"); works well.

You can configure qtcreator to clear the terminal before each run. Is that not good enough?

I need to clear terminal during the program execution. Show interface, than clear. Show interface, than clear...

See https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTCREATORBUG-30737 for a bug report regarding this exact issue.
Qt Creator 13.0.1 has a fix, or you can workaround by giving the TERM environment variable the proper value.
$ export TERM=xterm-256color


    #include <stdlib.h>
    
        const char *term = getenv("TERM");
    #ifdef _WIN32
        if (term == nullptr){
            _putenv("export TERM=xterm-256color");
        } else if (strlen(term) == 0){
            _putenv("export TERM=xterm-256color");
        }
    #else
        if (term == nullptr){
            setenv("TERM", "xterm-256color", 1);
        }
        else if (strlen(term) == 0){
            setenv("TERM", "xterm-256color", 1);
        }
    #endif

